# Strategy for package searching

Tags: package-management

I am using 11.10 the amd64 version (I assume, but I don't know how to figure that out). Now when I add a section to `/etc/apt/source.list.d/foo.list`:

```
deb http://<myserver>/download/public stable main
```

and put my package in

```
http://<myserver>/download/public/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/
```

I get an error:

```
Err http://<myserver> stable/main i386 Packages            
   404  Not Found
```

Now the question is: do I have to provide a `Packages(.gz)` in the `binary-i386` subdirectory even if it is empty? This is not a `i386` package and I don't request one on the command line. Does Ubuntu require both architectures to be available?

Comment: `dpkg --print-architecture` will show you what architecture dpkg is configured for.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Packages.gz file to make it a proper repository. If it is empty, just wait adding it to sources.list until you have finished setting it up.

See http://mediakey.dk/~cc/howto-create-your-own-debian-or-ubuntu-package-repository/ for detailed instructions, including generating Packages.gz

To verify your architecture, run `uname -m` in a terminal. If it is a 64-bit machine, it should report `x86_64`.

Comment: Obviously my question was bad. I have tried to rephrase it: I provide a `amd64` package but not a `i386` package. It used to work fine on a `i386` system, but somehow not when I am on a `amd64`.